# How to fix the Strideable protocol error?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code, but the compiler gives an error

> Type 'String.Index' does not conform to protocol 'Strideable'

While I was looking for, I encountered many similar questions, tried several suggested options - but this did not help get rid of the problem.

I'm sorry, I'm not very good at this and just trying to run the code of old version of Swift in my Swift 4 project.

Error on the line

```
roz.endIndex
```

```
let t = myHTMLString
let rangeOfZero = t.range(of: "[\"fmt_stream_map\"", options: .backwards)

 if let roz = rangeOfZero {

   if let suffix = t.characters.suffix(roz.endIndex) {

     first = suffix
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to get the substring from the end of the found range to the end of the string.

In Swift 4 you can use

```
let t = myHTMLString
if let roz = t.range(of: "[\"fmt_stream_map\"", options: .backwards) {
    first = String(t[roz.upperBound...])
}
```

Comment: If also rewrite another line?   
`String(first.characters.prefix(upTo: rangeOne!.startIndex))` is
`String(first[roz.lowerBound...])` ?

Comment: No, `String(first[..<roz.lowerBound])`